# for loop causing deadlock

Tags: go, concurrency

I have written some code example from [GO Concurrency](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) :

```
func gen(numbers ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for _, number := range numbers {
            out <- number
        }
        close(out)
    }()

    return out
}

func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for number := range in {
            out <- number * number
        }
    }()

    return out
}
```

so I tried to use above code in my main function like this :

```
func main() {



    result := sq(sq(sq(gen(1, 2, 3, 4))))

    fmt.Println(<-result)
    fmt.Println(<-result)
    fmt.Println(<-result)
    fmt.Println(<-result)

    fmt.Println("-------------------")

    for channelValue := range sq(sq(sq(gen(1, 2, 3, 4)))) {
        fmt.Println(channelValue)
    }

}
```

I was confused when I run the code I got this message after the loop:

> fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Please help me to understand this. From what I understand is calling the `fmt.Prinlnt(result)` x 4 times is the same as the for loop on `for channelValue := range sq(sq(sq(gen(1, 2, 3, 4))))`. is this correct?

Could please tell me why I got deadlock after the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range over the channel blocks because the channel is not closed in sq.

```
func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
  out := make(chan int)

  go func() {
    for number := range in {
        out <- number * number
    }
    close(out)
  }()

  return out
}
```

A good way to debug deadlocks like this is to send the process a SIGQUIT. The runtime dumps the stacks of all the goroutines when a SIGQUIT is received. The stack dumps will often point to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing the `out` channel in the `sq` function

```
go func() {
    for number := range in {
        out <- number * number
    }
    close(out)
}()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/kk8-08SfwB